# I am trying to use lettergothic font in my document. I am getting an error "The ulgb8r source file could not be found."

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex

I am using pdflatex compiler. This is a sample document. After installing font manually as directed in the README.lettergothic, I have performed "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Formats" of my Miktex 2.9 using Settings. But unable to use the font. I tried searching an found that this could be due to absence of .mf files. I tried to google but couldn't found mf files or a way to create .mf files.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ulgothic}

\begin{document}
\texttt{This is test text.}
\end{document}
```

The log file is as following:

```
{C:/Users/Jitendra/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}  
Trying to make PK font ulgb8r at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The ulgb8r source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font ulgb8r could not be created.

!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file ulgb8r): Font ulgb8r at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably need to run `updmap` or the equivalent for MiKTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did as told now it is showing " error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file ulgb8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font fil
e for reading" . However the file exists.

Comment: The `ulgothic` package appears to have been removed from the CTAN, and it's also no longer on TeXlive. Anyone know when and why the package was removed?

Comment: The package is under the  name 'lettergothic' and here is the link http://ctan.org/pkg/lettergothic.

Comment: @Mico: It disappeared  as an individual folder, and is to be found on CTAN in  `/fonts/urw/lettergothic`. There is a direct in the TeX Catalogue.

Comment: @Mico Has it ever been in TeX Live? Not for several years anyhow. It can be installed, I think, using `getnonfreefonts(-sys)`. I don't know about MikTeX.

Comment: The package contains a .zip file which respects the TDS, so it is enough to unzip it at the root of your local texmf directory. Only the `.afm,  .pfm` and `.pfb` files have to be installed by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1) Write `Map ulg.map` in your personal `updmap.cfg`, to be found in `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config`. If it doesn't exist, create it.

2) Run `updmap` (*as administrator* if you have a multiuser installation, and you want all users to have access to the font).

Then it should work. At least, the following worked on my system (MiKTeX 2.9, Windows 7), where you can see both `lmtt` and `ulgothic` (unscaled, as I did not use the package):

[image]

Comment: Step 2 depends on the current state of the system. If the user did run updmap once (e.g. due to on-the-fly installation) then user map files exist and they must be updated as user.  Why do you always insist on the "do something as admin"?

Comment: That's because I installed my own system for all users, and I do all updates as administrator. Never do on-the-fly installation (but it's very useful to warn  me a package is missing).

Comment: But it is not your system that matters but the system of the OP. I have a single user installation and nevertheless take into account in my answers multiuser systems.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher: I modified my answer to take your comment into account. The only problem is I prefer to check first my answers, and in the single-user case, it's purely conjectural. Perhaps on-the-fly installation should give a choice for the installation mode.

Comment: It is not about single-user installation. Your answer is wrong for a multiuser system. You are not taking into account that in a multiuser installation users can install packages, that they can have their own user settings, and that the admin can not change them. Would you change the background color of  your desktop by switching to the admin account and adjust the color there?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: It's hard for me to figure out all the details, as I systematically install packages for every user. I've modified again my answer. Is that correct now?

Comment: That didn't help. Could you please write the whole procedure of installing the font. I followed the manual of the font to install but it didn't work. Or if you are able to make it an installable package. Or if there is a tutorial to make latex font so that I could do it myself. I tried googling but couldn't find any tutorial.

Comment: This is the warning I am getting now:  `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/ulgothic/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using 'T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7`.

Comment: I can make an installable .zip file, but where can I upload it?

Comment: You can upload to google drive and provide the link here.

Comment: @Jitendra Kumar: You can download `mylettergothic.zip` from [here](http://dl.free.fr/kg0bU1g7o). It constains an `installation instructions` file. The rest is ready to install. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. It worked for me.